# Unable to see collections in mongo DB when connected through R

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

I used "rmongodb" package to connect to mongo DB through R.
The connection is successful.

```
> mongo.is.connected(mongo)
[1] TRUE
>
```

If I check at the host where mongoDB is running.

```
> use reporting
switched to db reporting

> show collections
MongoIndexing
details
test
>
```

But from R

```
> mongo.get.database.collections(mongo , db="reporting")
character(0)
>
```

Comment: try this `mongo.get.database.collections(mongo , "reporting");`

Comment: The accepted answer seems to suffer from this open issue: https://github.com/dselivanov/rmongodb/issues/93

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will return an array of collection names iff the provided database has collections in it. Otherwise, it will return `character(0)`

try this:

```
mongo <- mongo.create(host="127.0.0.1:27017" , db="sample")
mongo.get.database.collections(mongo , "sample")
```

Output: two collections named roles and categories

```
"sample.roles"          
"sample.categories"
```

To get all databases:

```
mongo <- mongo.create(host="127.0.0.1:27017")
mongo.get.databases(mongo)
```

To get all collections in a specific database say sample:

```
mongo.get.database.collections(mongo, "sample")
```

You can check [rmongod](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmongodb/vignettes/rmongodb_introduction.html) link for more info.

Comment: How can I switch database in R once connection is made to mongodb. Like we do in mongodb "use <database>"

Comment: You have to create a new connection to the database that you want `mongo <- mongo.create(host=XXX, db =YYY`  and then use this object whenever you do a query or something