# When using rmongodb, unable to see collections in mongoDB

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

I am having the same issue as in this thread:[Unable to see collections in mongo DB when connected through R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582323/unable-to-see-collections-in-mongo-db-when-connected-through-r)

I am successfully connected to mongoDB.

```
> mongo.is.connected(mongo)
[1] TRUE
```

If I run the following code, I see the correct db.

```
> mongo.get.databases(mongo)
[1] "FF"
>
```

But, when I try to view the collections, it returns character(0)

```
> mongo.get.database.collections(mongo , db = "FF")
character(0)
>
```

If I connect from the shell I can see all the collections, so I know they exist.

```
> use FF
switched to db FF

> show collections
kelp_classifications
kelp_groups
kelp_subjects
kelp_users
```

Comment: I just solved the issue by reverting to mongoDB ver. 3.0.8.

Answer (score 1):

#### Update 2017-09-25

`rmongodb` is no longer supported and removed from CRAN

Reference: https://github.com/dselivanov/rmongodb

---

This function is working correctly for me in `v1.8.0`:

```
mongo <- mongo.create()
mongo.is.connected(mongo)
# [1] TRUE
db <- "test"
mongo.get.database.collections(mongo, db = db)
[1] "test.test"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to work in situations where mongo.get.database.collections(mongo, db = db) results in character(0)

```
mongo = mongo.create(host = "127.0.0.1:9997", db = "restaurant")

# Create a mongo.bson object with header as "listCollections", which is 
# a mongo DB command
command = list(listCollections = "") 
command = mongo.bson.from.list(command)
command
>listCollections : 2     

# calling mongo DB server to return collections as mongo.bson object
collections = mongo.command(mongo, "restaurant", command)

# convert mongo.bson object to a list 
collections = mongo.bson.to.list(collections)
```