# Unable to see any collection in rmongodb of any db

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

I have tried everything to get collections out in R, but all in vain
I have followed the following links as well:

[When using rmongodb, unable to see collections in mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752065/when-using-rmongodb-unable-to-see-collections-in-mongodb)

[Unable to see collections in mongo DB when connected through R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582323/unable-to-see-collections-in-mongo-db-when-connected-through-r)

while `mongo.is.connected(mongo)` gives true, it fails to fetch the collections

However, `mongo.get.databases(mongo)` is fetching me all the databases in my system.

Comment: eventually, downgrading mongodb's version from 3.2 to 3.0 worked out for me :)